# How are EXE, DLL, SYS, etc. filetypes called together?

Tags: windows, terminology, executable

I'm wondering what's the proper name for all files with executable content? In .NET world, it's called an assembly. Any generic term in Windows world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Portable Executable* encompasses them all; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable (Of which .net executables are an extended form)

Answer (score 5):

I just call them *binaries* or *executables*.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows they are called *Modules*. It is called this way:

1. In windbg, to list them, the command is `lm` for "List Modules".
2. In tasklist / tlist.exe, the command line switch is `-m` to find modules.
3. `LoadLibrary` and other MSDN documentation refers to them this way. Also see `GetModuleHandle`.

And countless other examples exist.